# Auto Increment unique to a different Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

what i am trying to do is create a table that looks something like this....

```
ID as int
auto as int--this will be unique but only to the ID field
other fields....
```

meaning i want something like this...

```
ID|Auto|other fields
--------------------
1 | 1 | ....
-------------------
1 | 2 | ....
-------------------
2 | 1 | ....
-------------------
2 | 2 | ....
-------------------
```

is there a way to get SQL to do this automatically?

Comment: In a query or stored in the database?

Comment: i think i will try going with triggers for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 'auto' field a normal auto-increment.  When you read it from the database, you can select `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY auto)` to get the answer you want.

I realize this is a "How do X?  No, you should do Y instead" style answer, but there are really good reasons to let the DB handle auto-increment fields instead of rolling your own solution with triggers.  Maybe you could expand on why you want to store this data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

try using `row_number()` with `partition` `clause`

like this:

`select *,Auto=row_number()over(partition by id order by id) from table`

Comment: This is how I would do it in a query but It seems to me the user may want this stored in the database.

Comment: my only fear with this is that this is for a chat/messaging type of structure and the id will be the message id and the auto will be the line... and i do not want 2 users using the same line number
but at the same token i do not want line numbers being totally unique  becuase they may get out of hand

Answer (score 0):

"ID" is short for "identity" or "identifier", which usually implies uniqueness.  I'm assuming you want an increment based on another column, not a unique column.

The first solution that comes to mind is a trigger, which will allow you to modify the row after the insert has occurred.

Be careful, as you may have to account for odd cases--for example, what should happen if a row at the start or middle of the sequence is deleted?  Do all rows get re-ordered?

A timestamp for when the row is written might be a better solution if you need to order the rows in a query later.

Comment: i am thinking i like this idea i may just use SYSDATETIME() but i can still get duplicates that way

Comment: If two rows get insert at the *exact* same time (very unlikely), how would you break the tie?  It seems at that point that the order is probably arbitrary anyway?

Answer (score 0):

On your insert statement, you will need to select the maximum auto and add 1:

```
insert into table
select
    ((select max(auto) from table where id = id) + 1) as auto
   ,nextfield1
   ,nextfield2
...
```

Comment: but with this i would still be concerned about "collisions"

Comment: You could do something like this in an insert trigger as well if you are worried about timing. How do you think this will cause "collisions"?

Comment: well if 2 people try to add a line to the DB they may both get the same auto (line number) and that would not be good

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your implementation details are, but this is the sort of thing that the [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) data type was designed to address.

Here's some [general information on hierarchical data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) in SQL Server.

At only two levels deep, your situation might not be a good fit for it, but there is a big benefit in establishing a model with flexibility and room for change.

Caveat emptor - It does come with some limitations, such as a lack of support in Entity Framework.

**Update**: Note that this would consolidate your two columns into a single column.